# Gradle compileJava fails due to missing excluded dependency

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

stupid question but I am a little lost here.

i exclude slf4j-api from configuration compile.

```
configurations {
       compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
       compile.exclude module: "tomcat-embed-el"
       compile.exclude module: "logback-classic"
       compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
       compile.exclude module: "slf4j-api"
     }
```

No I can't compile the classes anymore because of the missing slf4j dependency, which will be provided later by an container. I tried to add

```
compileOnly group:....
providedCompile group ....
provided (plugin by netflix)
```

but so far it is not working. always getting the error

```
can not find symbol org.slf4j....
import failed .....
```

so how do I add an compileOnly dependency in gradle that is recognized?

Regards
Mathias

Comment: to start with: I'm not that familiar with Gradle so sorry for any stupidity, I'm just having fun trying to help:) so have you tried `compileOnly` like [here](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies)?

Comment: compileOnly should work. What I think is the problem is that you are excluding it globally. Try to exclude it at module level (as a property of particular artifact which pulls it in), rather than globally - it might help. On tangential note, excluding slf4j-api is not best practice. Idea is that you bundle slf4j-api with your application, container provides actual _implementation_ of it, rather than even interfaces themselves.

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich thanks for the try :) I read that link already but it didn't help

Comment: @Mathias Maerker Artur seems to be right. It actually was my thoughts

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski I could exclude it on each and every module, but that is cluttering up the build.gradle a lot, so I thought to exclude it globally. but if there is no other way I do it per module. Unfortunately I have no control over the container, it is a PaaS system, and their documentation states that ALL slf4j-api dependencies have to be excluded

Comment: What you could possibly do is to script it up. Gradle is groovy after all, you could write a small piece of code to iterate through all dependencies and add slf4j excludes automatically. Not very nice, but maybe better and more future proof than doing it many times by hand for each module. Unfortunately, I cannot try it out atm to provide example code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried **compileOnly** instead of  **compile.exclude module**, like for servlet api it will be like this

compileOnly 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I excluded per module. If I have the time to write a script for this I will post it here. Thanks to everybody
Regards
Mathias